# Extend HashMap to add putChildren method

Tags: java, hashmap

I have question, I want to develop a programme about extend the hashmap to add putchildren method..
I wrote main class, but now I want to write putChildrenValue method..
My question is :
I need to implement a putChildrenValue method with 3 parameters, String key, String key, ObjectValue. It will store the system as described above accordingly.

When I finished this method When you finish the method data

```
Key1 = "RUBY" value=HashMap which has -> "key2" = 5248 && "VALUE" = German
Key1 = "PYTHON" value=HashMap which has -> "key2" = 1234 && -> "VALUE" = German
```

My main class is :

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    ExtendedHashMap extendedMap = new ExtendedHashMap();
    extendedMap.put (“Row1”, “Column1”, “German”);
    extendedMap.put (“Row1”, “Column2”, “English”);
    extendedMap.put (“Row1”, “Column3”, “Spanish”);
    extendedMap.put (“Row2”, “Column1”, “Ruby”);
    extendedMap.put (“Row2”, “Column2”, “Python”);
    extendedMap.put (“Row3”, “Column3”, “Java”);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any code for ExtendedHashMap yet?  And have you been told that it has to be Hashmap, or was that your choice?  It seems like there are other data structures that might be better suited to what you are trying to do.

Comment: The concept of children doesn't make sense for a `Map`. Are you building a tree? If so, consider composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

It could go like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ExtHashMap<K1, K2, V> extends HashMap<K1, HashMap<K2, V>> {

  public ExtHashMap() {
    super();
  }

  public void putChildrenValue(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {

    HashMap<K2, V> childMap = get(key2);
      if (childMap == null) { 
        childMap = new HashMap<K2, V>();
        put(key1, childMap);
      }
      childMap.put(key2, value);
    }
  }
}
```

The following snippet gives an example on how to create and use it:

```
ExtHashMap<String, int, String> map = new ExtHashMap<String, int, String>();
map.putChildValue("RUBY", 1234, "VALUE1");
map.putChildValue("PYTHON", 4321, "VALUE2");
```

The childmaps are autocreated on demand.